# bpy python: firing a function when an object gets edited

Tags: python

whenever an object gets edited I need to update some metadata linked to the geometry of that object. I found that bpy.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append could append a callback function, but I have not managed to get it to behave predictably, the documentation was a little terse in this regard.
Does anybody know of an example script with this behavior that I can study, or have other nuggets of wisdom that could help me move forward on this ?

thank you,
S

Comment: Is it for any object or for some objects linked with your (I suppose to be) addon?

Comment: This is for objects (only meshes) I imported with my script.

Comment: So that can interest you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/know-when-edit-mode-is-entered-by-script-python/169290#169290 that can be done at object level, not context/scene level (afaik)